# Your app cannot be published yet. Complete the steps listed on the Dashboard

Tags: google-play-console

Your app cannot be published yet. Complete the steps listed on the Dashboard. While every step is completed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hssQ8.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing last two options
**Create merchant account** and **Set the price of your app**
Because you may have declared somewhere that your app is a paid app not the free one,
if yes you may need to complete the **Set Up Pricing**

If your app is free please declare it.

for ref:
use this link
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en

Comment: App was marked as paid